# If in a certain school 20 students play football, 10 play basketball and 7 play both

Tags: probability

If in a certain school 20 students play football, 10 play basketball and 7 play both and a student is selected at random, what is the probability that student plays exactly one game?

a) 7/30

b) 16/23

c) 8/15

d) 7/23

e)1

Comment: You need to know how many students play no sports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 10 students play basketball and $7$ play both that means there are $10-7=3$ students playing only basketball. Analogically there are $20-7=13$ students playing only football. So the total number of students is $13+3+7=23$.
 The students playing exactly one game are $3+13=16$, and the total number of students is $23$ therefore the probability is $16/23$.

Answer (score 0):

$7$ play both, so $3$ only play basketball and $13$ only play football. So the number of students playing only one game is $20$. The total number of students is $13+3+7=23$ (the number of students playing a single game plus the number of students playing both). So the correct answer is b.

(this is assuming that no student plays neither of the sports)

Answer (score 0):

The total number of students must be 23 looking at it like:

Just football: x x x x x x x x x x x x x   (13)

Both: x x x x x x x  (7)

Just basketball: x x x  (3)

The number that play exactly 1 sport is 16, so you have $16/23$.